# How do I get no console messages when I use the console?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I noticed on my server that when I type in any command in the server console that it makes a message that all the players can see. Is there a way to make it so that players can't see those messages?

Comment: Are you sure this is actually publically visible, as opposed to visibly only to players with operator permissions?

Comment: I checked, and it's only visible to opped players. Thanks for clarifying